# calculating excel formula using powershell

Tags: powershell, excel-formula

I am having below data in excel sheet (e.g. it's for 1 day and for 5 mins sample
So 2022-10-23 01:35:00 PM will have multiple rows, 2022-10-23 01:40:00 PM will have multiple rows and so on)

**SLA sheet**

```
SYMM_ID     DATE                    INSTANCE    Total Response Time Host MBs Read/sec   Host MBs Written/sec    Host Reads/sec  Host Writes/sec
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_PRDPRF    0.44                579.25              14.23                   4405.09         142.27
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_PRDPRF    0.26                29.89                0.97                   4041.24         103.99
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_PRDPRF    0.49                187.3              162.67                   3779.49         7470.4
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_PRDSTD    0.41                 4.16                1.45                    213.21         200.95
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_NPRDSTD   0.53                 0.01                0.03                      0.03           3.31
297900076   2022-10-23 01:30:00 PM  L_NPRDSTD   0.57                    0                0.01                      0              2.18
```

I am running the below formula and result I am getting in another sheet

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(SLA!$D:$D,SLA!$C:$C,"*_L_*STD",SLA!$B:$B,$B20,SLA!$D:$D,"<>0"),"-")
```

The output of the above formula giving me **1 row**. So for each date and time, the **SLA sheet** will have multiple rows but output is AVG of them as single row. so finally each date and time will have **1 row** in other sheet.

for a 30 days month, the output sheet should have 12*24*30 = 8640 rows ( 12 rows per hour, 24 hours a day and 30 day month)

The same I need to perform via powershell. I have done the formula part but the problem is I am not getting how to loop/perform that **8640 rows** part

Please need suggestions on this. let me know if any details missed.

Comment: Can you also include an example of that one row in the SLA Sheet?

Comment: @Theo: I have included the data is from SLA sheet.

Comment: Ummmm... I'm not seeing your edit..

Comment: @Theo: at the top I have mentioned `SLA sheet`